# How to create a ZF2 FormCollection of the Doctrine ORM Module's ObjectSelect elements?

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an odd situation where my add form works perfectly, but the edit form will not even load. Instead I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect::$object in /vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Element/Collection.php on line 517
>
> Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Element/Collection.php on line 517

I have objects of the class `Application\Model\Record` which have a many-to-many relationship to objects of the class `Application\Model\Subject`. I want the `Subjects` to appear as dropdowns in the `Record` forms, with the option to add multiple `Subjects`. So in the `RecordFieldset.php` I have:

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'subjects',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
    'options' => array(
        'label' => 'Subjects',
        'count' => 1,
        'should_create_template' => true,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'allow_remove' => true,
        'template_placeholder' => '__subjectindex__',
        'target_element' => array (
            'name' => 'subject',
            'type'  => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                'target_class' => 'Application\Model\Subject',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_option' => 'Select a subject',
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

And like I said, this works perfectly in the Record add form. But it looks like on the edit form it cannot load the Subjects. Has anyone else tried something like this? Or do you have an idea what the error is saying?

Environment:
Zend Framework 2.3.3
Doctrine-orm-module 0.8.0
Doctrine 2.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug on ZF2, target elements need to be a fieldset for it to work otherwise it will run into this issue. Use a fieldset to wrap the ObjectSelect.

Comment: Finally got around to fixing this. Wrapping the ObjectSelect in a Fieldset made the edit page work. Thanks!